# Hidden points with different markers

Tags: matlab, 3d, matlab-figure

How can I draw points and line which are not visible (they are hidden from certain point of view) - actually they are visible due to alpha, with different markers and line styles.
I can set all of the markers and lines, but I need them different in the background.

[image]

Comment: This particular plot is made in a single-command style, and not draw line by line and marker by marker controlling for transparency.

Comment: OK, but how can I create something similar?

Comment: That's certainly not matlab's usual way to plot. You can acheveive such a result by overlaying several identical surfaces and mesh, setting visibility to off. That's a tough job though, and not sure you will be able render an identical figure... Probably done with another environment?

Comment: ok, thank you for your response

Comment: @kubrdom I agree with what marsei is saying, there isn't really any easy to use framework within MATLAB (that I'm aware of) to do that.

Comment: Thank you. It is very strange. I guess all other soft which can render graphics - plots and so on, can do this effect natively. Now I think, I have to draw 2 plots, one is background ('--' line and 'o' markers) and second one is foreground('-' and black markers). Then I need to put it together. The really big fun will be drawing line, which has part '-' and another '--'.